# Why is this True ? It's probability question, but really an multivariable integration question

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

I'm given that $X$ is a non-negative continuous random variable show that

$$E(X) = \int^\infty_0 [1-F(x)]\,dx$$

$F(x)$is a cdf

The solution is following

$$\int^\infty_0 (1-F(x)) \, dx = \int^\infty_0 P(X > x) \, dx = \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_x f_x(t) \, dt\,dx = \int^\infty_0 f(t) \left(\int^t_0 dx\right) \, dt$$

I don't understand why is it true for the last two equality, when the order $dx$ and $dy$ been changed. What's the theorem behind it ? (i only know basic double integration calculation)

Comment: My answer might seem a bit long-winded, but I think it's simple and comprehensible, and if you're going to be working with integrals like this one it's something you should know. I remember in a statistical theory course doing dozens of multiple integrals that seemed exotic but turned out to be reducible to elementary methods by massaging things in various ways, and this is one of a bunch of basic tools for dealing with those. Working out the densities for $F$-distributions was one of the simpler things in that course, and right now I don't remember what other ones we did. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @ the answer is great and well-explained ! It really clears my doubts on double integral, change of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_x f_X(t) \, dt\,dx = \int^\infty_0 f_X(t) \left(\int^t_0 dx\right) \, dt\text{ ?}
$$

Firstly, I've changed $f_x$ to $f_X$ above, for a reason I expect will be clear to you since your writing $\Pr(X>x)$ would seem to indicate that you know the difference between $X$ and $x$.

$$
\int^\infty_0 \left(\int^\infty_x f_X(t) \, dt\right) \, dx
$$
The variable $x$ runs from $0$ to $\infty$.

For each value of $x$, the other variable $t$ runs from $x$ to $\infty$.

This says we're looking at the set of values of $x$ and $t$ for which $0<x<t<\infty$.

The the integral that is inside the other one says $\displaystyle\int_x^\infty\cdots\cdots \, dt$, so it is explicit about the thing over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ in this expression: $0<\underbrace{x<t<\infty}$.

Now let's look at $0<x<t<\infty$ in a different way: $\underbrace{0<x<t}<\infty$.

This says that for any particular value of $t$, the other variable, $x$, runs from $0$ to $t$.  As for $t$, it runs from $0$ to $\infty$.  So we have
$$
\int_0^\infty \cdots\cdots\,dt
$$
and then inside that, and so for every fixed value of $t$, we have $\displaystyle\int_0^t\cdots\cdots\,dx$.  So we have
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^x\cdots\cdots\,dx \right)\,dt.
$$

This gets us
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^t f_X(t)\,dx \right)\,dt.
$$

In the inner integral, $\displaystyle\int_0^t f_X(t)\,dx$, notice that as $x$ runs from $0$ to $t$, $f_X(t)$ does not change, since the variable $x$ does not appear within it. Since $f_X(t)$ does not depend on $x$, the inner integral is equal to
$$
f_X(t) \int_0^t 1\,dx.
$$

Comment: that's brilliant explanation, thanks so much !!

Comment: @Hobbit6094 : Thank you.

Comment: @Hobbit6094: Note that one cannot always interchange integrals. In this case it happens that Fubini's theorem guarantees that you can do so.

Comment: @user21820 : And so does Tonelli's theorem, which says they can be interchanged as long as the function being integrated is everywhere non-negative, even if the value of the integral is infinite.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yup. I just thought it is important to point it out lest people simply assume it is true without justification. =)

Answer (score 2):

You are switching the order of integration over a region that is an infinite triangle, that is the region between $x=0$ and the line $x=t$ in the first quadrant; the first expression integrates from the line to infinity first, whereas the second integrates from zero to the line first.

Answer (score 1):

It's a change of order of integration.

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^x f_X(t)\operatorname d t\operatorname d x
& = \iint_{0 \leq x \leq t < \infty} f_X(t)\operatorname d t\operatorname d x
\\ & = \iint_{0 \leq x \leq t < \infty} f_X(t)\operatorname d x\operatorname d t
& \text{via Fubini's theorem}
\\ & = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^t f_X(t)\operatorname d x\operatorname d t
\\ & = \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(t) \int_{0}^t \operatorname d x\operatorname d t
\\ & = \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(t) t\operatorname d t
\end{align}

Comment: I hadn't thought of using \operatorname{d}t in this way before.  It puts spaces both before and after the "d", thus $\displaystyle \int f(x)\operatorname{d}x$.  I've always put a space before but not after that: $\displaystyle\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.  Do you have a distinct preference for putting a space after the "d"? ${}\qquad{}$